# Recover Time Machine sparsebundle backup

Tags: macos, time-machine, fsck, sparsebundle, hdiutil

I have a Time Machine backup from an old computer that I can't open. When I double click on the sparsebundle file, I get "no mountable filesystems".

I've next tried this:

```
hdiutil attach -nomount -noverify -noautofsck Emily’s\ iMac.sparsebundle
```

This returns just this:

```
/dev/disk3
```

All of the other searches indicate it should return Apple_partition_scheme, Apple_partition_map, and Apple_HFSX devices but I only see the one.

The sparsebundle is 111G so I know it has something in it.

I then tried fsck_hfs:

```
fsck_hfs -drf /dev/disk3
journal_replay(/dev/disk3) returned 22
** /dev/rdisk3
    Using cacheBlockSize=32K cacheTotalBlock=65536 cacheSize=2097152K.
   Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-556.60.1).
    Block 2 is not an MDB or Volume Header 
    Block 3902834782 is not an MDB or Volume Header 
volumeType is 0
/dev/rdisk3 0000:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       |................|
. . .
/dev/rdisk3 01f0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       |................|
    unknown volume type 
    primary MDB is at block 0 0x00 
    alternate MDB is at block 0 0x00 
    primary VHB is at block 0 0x00 
    alternate VHB is at block 0 0x00 
    sector size = 512 0x200 
    VolumeObject flags = 0x01 
    total sectors for volume = 3902834784 0xe8a08860 
    total sectors for embedded volume = 0 0x00 
    CheckForClean - unknown volume type 
    CheckHFS returned 6, fsmodified = 0
```

Is there any way to mount this backup? I just need to get lost pictures from this old computer. :(